# How to use Random.Rotation() method on a cube?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner to Unity Development and came through a task of rotating cube Randomly. I saw many sources but was getting confused about connecting the Cube to the script on Button button click.

Currently, I am doing this:

```
void Update()
{
    transform.rotation = Random.rotation;
}
```

on the script and adding it to the cube but doing it on button click sounds tricky. Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Never thought Tony Stark would need help in developing.

Comment: Haha, that's was savage but yeah at my age even tony would be a newbie possibly.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a collider on the cube, you can add to the cube's script

```
void OnMouseDown() 
{
    transform.rotation = Random.rotation();
}
```

which will be run whenever the collider detects a click.

Comment: Works perfectly fine thank you.

Comment: Hey, no problem at all. We all gotta start out somewhere. If you don't already know and use it, check out [the unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/index.html) for lots of information.

Comment: Actually many of the docs have been rolled back too because of Unity 5's new upgrades like now mesh filter & rigid body cannot be used on the same gameobject.